# Where unmanaged resources are allocated

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I am not a comp science guy. Managed resources are allocated on the heap. But I would like to know where unmanaged resources are allocated. If unmanaged resources are also allocated on the heap, is it the same heap used by managed resources or a different one?

Thanks in advance.

Harsha

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Essentially the heap is the same speaking from the operating system view: the memory space assigned to the OS process.

The difference is that when the CLR (.net VM) loads inside a Windows process it takes a piece of this heap and turns it into a **managed heap**. This memory space becomes the place where all managed resources are allocated and known to the garbage collector.

For instance, you can run into a Out of Memory error if you allocate a big chunk of unmanaged memory and run out of space for your managed heap. Or the other way around.

Jeffrey Richter is the guy that better explains this stuff. I highly recommend reading his explanation:

- [Garbage Collection: Automatic Memory Management in the Microsoft .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx)
- [Garbage Collection Part 2: Automatic Memory Management in the Microsoft .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985011.aspx)

You can use the services of the System.InteropServices namespace, the [Marshal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal(v=VS.80).aspx) class specifically, to copy data between the unmanaged part of the heap and the managed.

Comment: It is a really good article. For completeness i also added the second part of it.

Comment: @Oliver: excellent! thanks for editing the question instead of just posting it in a comment.

Comment: Yes, that's one of the nice features when you earned enough rep (like you already did, too). ;)

Answer (score 1):

To operate with unmannaged heap use Marshal class described at MSDN

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal(v=vs.71).aspx

Unmanaged heap doesn't controlled by GC, so all responsibility of memory usage lies on you. Essentially to release memory that allocated for unmanaged resources use IDisposable interface and release all allocated resources by yourself. All unmanaged resources like SQL connections and different IO operations are using this approach.

Answer (score 0):

In memory. Like for any unmanaged process.. THe managed heap obviously is different from the managed one.

Comment: Actually, unmanaged resources could be anywhere--not necessarily on the machine where the object encapsulating the resource is located.  A couple of common example of an off-machine resources would be a file on a remote server, or a TCP connection to a very-resource-limited device (e.g. many embedded devices only support one TCP connection at a time).  If a routine were to acquire such a file or TCP connection and not immediately release it, it could leave such a resource at least temporarily inaccessible from users on other machines.

Comment: No. See "a file on a remote server" is still allocated locally for management. To keep it open you need a file share which incidentally does not amgically appear, it is bound to a file open operation on the local server#s file management stack. A TCP connection also somehow uses a local socket.

Comment: Although most operating systems will manage things like TCP sockets and remote file handles, and clean them up when an application exits, the thing that is *scarce* is the resource on the remote machine.  The fact that the local machine's OS keeps a reference to the remote file and can clean it up if and when the application exits doesn't mean that users on other machines, who neither know about nor care about anything to do with the machine that opened the file, would be left unable to access the file on the remote machine until that happened.

Answer (score 0):

The CLR maintains its own heaps.  Initially, two are created: one is simply called the [managed heap](http://codebetter.com/blogs/raymond.lewallen/archive/2005/07/10/128999.aspx) (or small object heap) and the other is the [large object heap](http://blogs.msdn.com/maoni/archive/2006/04/18/large-object-heap.aspx) (see also [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc534993.aspx)).  These managed heaps are physically separate from the native heaps allocated by the CRT for use with `new` and `malloc`.

You can use [VMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533.aspx) to inspect the different heaps allocated by a process.

Answer (score 0):

To borrow a turn of phrase from a magazine article that compared linear and non-linear filters, a comparison of managed resources and unmanaged resources is like a comparison between kangaroo biology and non-kangaroo-biology.

In .net, managed resources are class objects on the managed heap.  Always.  It's possible for value types to hold references to managed resources, but a value-type instance cannot itself "be" a managed resource.

By contrast, an unmanaged resource can be just about anything, and can be stored just about anywhere.  It need not be on the same computer, or even the same planet, as the program which owns it (I don't know that any of the probes that have been sent to Mars expose any sort of communications-socket interface which would behave as an unmanaged resource, but one could certainly design them to do so).

An object holds an unmanaged resource if some outside entity is doing something on behalf of that object, to the detriment of others, and will keep doing that something until it's told to stop (or, possibly, until it times out).  There are many kinds of unmanaged resources, and they can live just about anywhere.  Some of them (e.g. locks and event subscriptions) may live entirely within the managed world of .net.  Some of them (e.g. server connections) may exist outside the computer that "owns" them at any given moment.  Some types of unmanaged resources may encapsulate blocks of memory from the OS, separate from the unmanaged heap, but there is no general place unmanaged resources are "stored".  Rather, as noted, unmanaged resources can be just about anything, and can be stored just about anywhere.